# SQL Case When Slowing Down Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

What I'm looking to do is quantify the total value of purchases and the number of months in which a purchase was made within three different timeframes by account. I only want to look at accounts who made a purchase between 1-1-2020 and 4-1-2021.

I'm wondering if there is a more streamlined way to pull in the fields I'm creating using CASE WHEN below (maybe through a series of queries to create the calculations and the left joining?). This query is taking extremely long to pull back, so I'd like to enhance this code where I can. All of my code and desired output is listed below. Thank you!

Creating a temporary table to pull account numbers:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #accounts

SELECT DISTINCT s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc
INTO #accounts
FROM sales AS s
LEFT JOIN customer AS c ON s.account_no = c.account_no
WHERE s.tran_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01'
GROUP BY s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc;
```

Confirming row counts:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM #accounts
ORDER BY account_no;
```

Creating Sales and Sales period count columns for three timeframes:

```
SELECT 
    s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN s.tran_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01' 
                THEN VALUE_USD 
        END) AS Total_Spend_Pre,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN s.tran_date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2022-03-31' 
                THEN VALUE_USD 
        END) Total_Spend_During,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN s.tran_date > '2022-04-01' 
                THEN VALUE_USD 
        END) Total_Spend_Post,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.tran_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01' THEN CONCAT(s.bk_month, s.bk_year) END) Pre_Periods,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.tran_date BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2022-03-31' THEN CONCAT(s.bk_month, s.bk_year) END) During_Periods,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.tran_date > '2022-04-01' THEN CONCAT(s.bk_month, s.bk_year) END) Post_Periods
FROM 
    sales AS s
LEFT JOIN 
    customer AS c ON s.account_no = c.account_no
WHERE 
    c.account_no IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_no
                     FROM #accounts)
GROUP BY 
    s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc;
```

Desired output:

| account_no | code | code_desc | Total_Spend_Pre | Total_Spend_During | Total_Spend_Post | Pre_Periods | During_Periods | Post_Periods |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1234 | OTHER | 1000 | 2005 | 500 | 2 | 14 | 5 |
| 11 | 5678 | PC | 500 | 100 | 2220 | 5 | 11 | 2 |

Comment: Not going to make this an answer - but I would definitely tune the columns on the tables and the query first .  Start with using date data types in the query - convert(date,'2020-01-01',23) - then check the columns trans_date and value_usd , bk_month, bk_year in are in  non-clustered index

Comment: The case expressions are unlikely to be a performance issue, usage of distinct and group by together though is a *code smell*, you could replace the `in` with `exists`, but advice on performance really requires full table and index details and the actual execution plan (pastetheplan).

Comment: I suggest you apply a filter to the sales table that encompasses the complete set of dates of concern. It seems you could apply the condition "s.tran_date >= '2020-01-01' " to help the optimizer but much depends on the quantity and distribution of rows in that table. That might not work depending on the goal. But really, you need to look at the execution plan.

Comment: Why do you outer join the customer table? Is it even possible for a sales row to have an account_no for which there exists no entry in the customers table? The second outer join fails, by the way `WHERE c.account_no ...` turns it into an inner join as the condition removes all outer joined rows (for which account_no is null).

Comment: How are the tables related? Is the account_no unique in the customers table? Is it even the primary key and the sales.account_no a foreign key? Or can multiple customers share an account? It would be great if you could show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables` and tell us what indexes exist.

Answer (score 0):

You may use your date ranges to join with dataset, and 'Tag' your result like below, this will result in 3 rows, for each group. If you need them in a single row, have PIVOTE over it

```
;With DateRanges AS (
    SELECT CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE) StartDate, CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) EndDate, 'Pre' Tag UNION
    SELECT '2021-04-01', '2022-03-31', 'During' UNION
    SELECT '2022-04-01', Null, 'Post' 
)
SELECT s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc, d.Tag, 
SUM(VALUE_USD) AS Total_Spend,
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(s.bk_month, s.bk_year)) RecordCount
FROM sales as s
LEFT JOIN customer as c
INNER JOIN DateRanges D ON s.tran_date BETWEEN D.StartDate AND ISNULL(D.EndDate,s.tran_date)
ON s.account_no = c.account_no
WHERE c.account_no IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_no FROM #accounts)
GROUP BY s.account_no, c.code, c.code_desc;
```

Comment: Aggregate on as narrow data set as possible to improve performance - customer id and desc are decorations on the query - so aggreagation is not necessary - next answer is a longer winded way of the answer from Subodh Wasankar

Comment: In Subodh's answer, should ON s.account_no = c.account_no be between the LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN? With the code as is, I get a 'could not be bound' error. Also, should d.Tag be present in the Group By? @irnerd

Comment: Probably that's because of mismatch in date datatype. I tried to answer your question about how to improve performance by rewriting your query.  I can provide you exact query if you provide me with sample data and data types.

Answer (score 0):

```
with [cte_accountActivityPeriods] as (
select [PeriodOrdinal] = 1, [PeriodName] = 'Total Spend Pre', [PeriodStart] = convert(date,'2020-01-01',23) , [PeriodFinish] = convert(date,'2021-03-31',23) union
select [PeriodOrdinal] = 2, [PeriodName] = 'Total Spend During', [PeriodStart] = convert(date,'2021-04-01',23) , [PeriodFinish] = convert(date,'2022-03-31',23) union
select [PeriodOrdinal] = 3, [PeriodName] = 'Total Spend Post', [PeriodStart] = convert(date,'2022-04-01',23) , [PeriodFinish] = convert(date,'9999-12-31',23) 
)
, [cte_allsalesForActivityPeriod]
SELECT s.account_no,  bk_month, bk_year, [PeriodOrdinal], s.tran_date, s.value_usd
FROM sales as s
cross join [cte_accountActivityPeriods] 
  on s.[tran_date] between [cte_ActivityPeriods].[PeriodStart] and [cte_ActivityPeriods].[PeriodFinish]
)
, [cte_uniqueAccounts] as ( /*Unique and qualifying Accounts*/
select distinct account_no from [cte_allsalesForActivityPeriod]
inner join #accounts accs on accs.[account_no] = [cte_allsalesForActivityPeriod].[account_no]
)
, [cte_AllSalesAggregatedByPeriod] as (
select account_no,  [PeriodOrdinal], bk_month, bk_year, [PeriodTotalSpend] = sum([value_usd])
  from [cte_allsalesForActivityPeriod]
  group by s.account_no, [PeriodOrdinal],  bk_month, bk_year
)
, [cte_PeriodAnalysis] as (
select account_no,  [PeriodOrdinal], [ActivePeriods] = count(distinct concat(bk_month, bk_year))
  from [cte_AllSalesAggregatedByPeriod]
  group by s.account_no,  [PeriodOrdinal]
)
, [cte_pivot_clumsily] as (
/* Aggregations already done - so simple pivot */
select [cte_uniqueAccounts].[account_no]
     , [Total_Spend_Pre] = case when [SaleVal].[PeriodOrdinal] in (1) then [SaleVal].[PeriodTotalSpend] else 0 end
     , [Total_Spend_During] = case when [SaleVal].[PeriodOrdinal] in (2) then [SaleVal].[PeriodTotalSpend] else 0 end
     , [Total_Spend_Post] = case when [SaleVal].[PeriodOrdinal] in (3) then [SaleVal].[PeriodTotalSpend] else 0 end
     , [Pre_Periods] = case when [SalePrd].[PeriodOrdinal] in (1) then [SalePrd].[ActivePeriods] else 0 end
 , [During_Periods] = case when [SalePrd].[PeriodOrdinal] in (2) then [SalePrd].[ActivePeriods] else 0 end
     , [Post_Periods] = case when [SalePrd].[PeriodOrdinal] in (3) then [SalePrd].[ActivePeriods] else 0 end
  from [cte_uniqueAccounts] 
  left join [cte_AllSalesAggregatedByPeriod] [SaleVal] on [SaleVal].[account_no] = [cte_uniqueAccounts].[account_no]
  left join [cte_PeriodAnalysis] [SalePrd] on [SalePrd].[account_no] = [cte_uniqueAccounts].[account_no]
)
select c.code, c.code_desc, [cte_pivot_clumsily].*
from [cte_pivot_clumsily] 
LEFT JOIN customer as c
ON [cte_pivot_clumsily].account_no = c.account_no
```